# JQuery: removing all divs, classes and links anchor tag from string saved in variable

Tags: jquery

Using the JQuery, how do I remove divs, classes and links from a string that is saved in a variable?

Example:

```
var string = "<div class='mycls'>Go to <a href='/home'>Home</a> page."
```

Below is the result I want to achieve:

```
var string = "Go to Home page."
```

Comment: your question is not understandable please explain in depth

Comment: What you're asking and what you want are probably not the same. What about `title` attributes and other such HTML attributes? Do you want those removed too? What about tags that aren't div's like `span` etc? Do you want those removed?

Comment: I want to remove any divs, classes and links along with any of their attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can remove all HTML tags using regular expression, as below

```js
var string = "<div class='mycls'>Go to <a href='/home'>Home</a> page."
$("#converted").text(string.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, ''))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="converted"></p>
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

@Thinker, thank you and everyone for taking time to go through my post and comment. Below is what resolved the issue:

```
    var $temp = $("<span>").html(string);
    $temp.find("div").each(function() { $(this).replaceWith(this.childNodes); });
    var StringWithOutDivs = $temp.html();
```

Comment: this will remove only your div tags. @Thinker has given better solution to remove all HTML tags